# detete non-symmetric entries in sparse matrix python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix filled with symmetric and non-symmetric entries. I'm trying to filter out and remove all entries that are not symmetric. I'm using scipy sparse matrices.

My idea was to make the matrix symmetric, compare both, the symmetric and the original, and only take over entries that appear in both. Is there a way to implement this?
thanks for any ideas!